# Prove Z is not Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology

We have the subspace $Z = (\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}) \cup (\{0\} \times \mathbb{R})$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{R^2}$ and the function $g: \mathbb{R^2} \to Z$ defined as: $$g(x,y) = \begin{cases} (x,0) & \text{ if } & x \neq 0\\
 (0,y) &\text{ if } & x = 0\\
\end{cases}$$

In the first part of the problem I prove that this function $g$ is not continuous and closed but it is open.

And then in second part they asked me to prove that the quotient topology of $Z$ induced by $g$ is not $T_2$ (Hausdorff), and I don't know how to start to prove this.

Comment: Well, one thing to start is, what do you need to do to show that any space is not Hausdorff?

Comment: Well to show that I have to give two points that for any U,V open set from the topology that x $\in$ U and y $\in$ V the intersection between U and V is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you solved the first part of the exercise you should have realised that the problem is given by the $y$-axis in $Z$. According to the definition of quotient topology a subset $U \subset Z$ is open iff $g^{-1}(U)\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is open. If $z=(x,0)$ with $x \neq 0$ it is clear that it has an open neighbourhood of the form $\{(x+t,0) : -\epsilon < t < \epsilon \} $ for $\epsilon >0$ small enough, since its preimage via $g$ is just the column $\{(x+t,y): y \in \mathbb{R}, -\epsilon < t < \epsilon \}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Can you see that a point $z=(0,y)$ does not have open neighbourhoods in a similar form? When you understand their form you should be able to solve the problem quickly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why it's not Hausdorff, could you help me

Comment: Consider a point $(0,y) \in Z$ for some $y$ and let $U\subset Z$ be an open neighborhood in the quotient topology.  That is $g^{-1}(U)\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is open. It's easy to see that if $U$ is in the form $\{ (0,t) : t \in A \}$ for some subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ then $g^{-1}(U)$ contains $\{ (0,t) : t \in A\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$. But for this to be open it should contain also some element in for form $(\epsilon, y)$ with $\epsilon$ small enough. Thus $g(\epsilon,y) \in U$ and you get that every $U$ must contain also elements of the x-axis on the cross $Z$.

Comment: This holds for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$, so these $(0,y)$ do not admit disjoint neighbourhood.